# exchange keys , and ; in vim possible?

Tags: vim, remapping

Id like to exchange , and ; for moving to next and previous character-search, because that fits better the lowercase is next UPPERCASE is previous schema on a German Keyboard. But I don't know how.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are *normal-mode* commands; with `:nnoremap`, you avoid that the mapping targets are again remapped; this enables the swapping (and is generally a good practice to use). Put the following into your `~/.vimrc` to make it permanent:

```
:nnoremap ; ,
:nnoremap , ;
```

Comment: Still using this, works great on a German keyboard. :)